# Make a Function that Calls a Slide from a String eg string.label1.caption

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a function that does everything automatically.

Here's my current code:

```
Public Sub IncrementValueBeta(SlideDescription As String, SlideNumber As Integer, SlideName As String)
    ChangeSlide (SlideNumber)
    MsgBox ("Test: " + SlideDescription)
    AddClicks = SlideName.ClickedTimes.Caption + 1
    SlideName.ClickedTimes.Caption = AddClicks
End Sub
```

This will add a Number to the value but i'm trying to make shorter code it without having to do `if SlideName = "Slide1"` a 1000 times, it's a huge questionnaire.

What I'm trying to do here so the user will type `"SlideName"` e.g. `"Slide1"` and in the code it will use it like `Slide3.ClickedTimes.Caption = AddClicks` so in the slide if the slide was 25 clicks it would be 26 that's already working but only if I do  `Slide3` not `Slidename` is there a way I can do this? if you know how, can you help me because it will be a real pain if I have to do `If bah = "bah" then` `elseif bah = "bah" then` 1000 times, you know.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `Slides("Slide3").ClickedTimes.Caption = AddClicks` work for you? Because in that case you can replace `"Slide3"` (a constant)  with "SlideName" (a variable) and your problem is solved.